# Minimize a window into the Dock while Stage Manager is active?

Tags: macos, dock, stage-manager

OK, so I'm the sort of Mac user who is a little ridiculous and enjoys mixing and matching between systems and setups on the regular. I'm always changing my screen resolution to whatever is right in the moment. I switch Stage Manager off and on as the situation benefits. I may have a few screws loose.

So I love setting an app (or set of apps/windows) aside in Stage Manager's shelf, but that's the *most* useful for a select few "stages" I'm actively switching between (on a given desktop space). Sometimes there are just apps I'm not using right away and would like to keep stationary, minimized into the Dock. Plus, Dock-minimized windows are accessible no matter what desktop space or Stage Manager set I'm in, without occupying a chunk of the actual screen area like the "Assign To: All Desktops" Dock option does.

The trouble is, normal Dock minimizing *appears* to be disabled while Stage Manager is enabled. The yellow button (which still has a horizontal line looking like the Dock...) puts the window into a "minimized" state in the Stage Manager shelf if you've got multiple windows in the current set, or just slides away to reveal the desktop if it's the only thing currently visible. The "Minimize" option in the menu bar (or <kbd>⌘M</kbd>) does the same thing.

Despite that, Dock minimizing doesn't just stop existing entirely in Stage Manager! If I have a window minimized into the Dock *before* I enable Stage Manager, it *stays there* until I click it again.

[image: A minimized window while Stage Manager is active! How can it be!?]

It's so close to perfect! Yet, not quite... because once I click it, it's back to normal Stage Manager behavior. The window shows up in its own new set, and no matter what I try, I can't seem to get it back into the Dock. The window's minimize button slides it into the shelf, and that seems to be that.

So I'm wondering: **Are there any alternate methods for minimizing a window into the Dock, which still work while Stage Manager is active, instead of just stacking the window in Stage Manager's shelf?**

Answer (score 0):

Same here, I only found one solution on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/ydrcts/how_to_minimize_a_window_onto_the_dock_when_stage/) utilizing "better touch tools" for that, but I haven't tried that yet. There has to be some way to do this without making a shortcut mess that deactivates stage manager for a moment and then turns it back on after minimizing the window :(

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/339184)